# Fail instead of printing "Exception ignored in: <coroutine..."

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

When explicitly telling Python to treat a `RuntimeWarning` as an exception, the `Warning` becomes an `Exception` successfully. But now I get an `Exception ignored`, and the program still doesn't fail where it should. Minimal reproducible example:

```py
import asyncio
import warnings

async def main():
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("I don't want this printed.")

warnings.filterwarnings("error", category=RuntimeWarning)
asyncio.run(main())
```

```
Exception ignored in: <coroutine object sleep at 0x7f1e4f3d1b40>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/teresaejunior/.asdf/installs/python/3.9.2/lib/python3.9/warnings.py", line 506, in _warn_unawaited_coroutine
    warn(msg, category=RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2, source=coro)
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'sleep' was never awaited
I don't want this printed.
```

How can I stop Python from ignoring the exception raised by the `warnings` module?

Comment: "How can I stop Python from ignoring this, please?" always await a call to `asyncio.sleep`

Comment: @ranisalt I'll try to rewrite my question to avoid that, but I did mention in the first paragraph that I sometimes forget to include the await. I want Python to fail, not to ignore these kind of mistakes, and continue without sleeping...

Comment: @TeresaeJunior you may have picked the wrooooong language. How's it supposed to know that was mistake? That's a bit like blaming your car for not being a truck. You chose the car....

Comment: @JaredSmith the program is supposed to die when `warnings.filterwarnings("error", category=RuntimeWarning)` is set. It just doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I stop Python from ignoring this exception?

Sadly, I don't think you can, at least not in an obvious way. The problem is that this warning is printed while the coroutine object is being destroyed, that being the earliest point at which Python can be certain that you'll never await the coroutine.

Exceptions cannot be raised from destructors, because destructors are run during garbage collection and at other sensitive times. So when Python detects an exception at that time, it just ignores it, as the message says.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.  And that's a bummer. I think `RuntimeWarning: coroutine ... was never awaited` should be raised like an error by default. What is the point to not await a coroutine that's not assigned to anything? This is error prone.